# event triggered if input file is ready to be used by browser

Tags: angular

What event should be used with `<input type="file">` to be notified when the file is ready to be used by the browser?

So user clicks on `<input type="file">`, selects a file. Than I would like to use that file in the browser.

I tried `(ready)="functionName"` and `(change)="functionName"`, but I was kinda just making this events up :)

Comment: I guess you forget paranthesis while calling function on change event `functionName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` event should work:

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" />
```

with the event handler defined in the component class:

```
public fileChange(event: Event): void {
    let selectedFiles = (event.target as any).files;
    ...
}
```

Comment: ahh, I am such a retard sometimes. Glad to confirm that this works.